# Why are the selected values removed from the multi select in the admin page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I wrote a `multi-select form` for the admin page. The selected data is saved in the database, but for some reason it is not displayed as selected (no `selected` property).

When I try to save the object again, I get an error that the data in this field is not selected. It seems that when refresh the page, the selects just fly off.

What could be the problem?

I'm use `Django 1.9` and `django-jet`.

**models.py**

```
registration = models.CharField(_('registration'), max_length=255)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ConditionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    REGISTRATION_CHOICES= (
        ('Any', _('Any')),
        ('Constant', _('Constant')),
        ('Temporary', _('Temporary')),
    )

    registration = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = REGISTRATION_CHOICES, label=_("registration form"))

    def clean_registration(self):
        registration = self.cleaned_data['registration']
        if not registration:
            raise forms.ValidationError("...")

        registration = ', '.join(registration)
        return registration

    class Meta:
        model = Condition
        fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.py**

```
class ConditionInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Condition
    form = ConditionAdminForm
```

**admin html**

```html
<div class="form-row field-registration">
  <div>
    <label class="required" for="id_condition_set-0-registration">registration:</label>
    <select multiple="" id="id_condition_set-0-registration" name="condition_set-0-registration" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
      <option value="Any">Any</option>
      <option value="Constant">Constant</option>
      <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--jet" dir="ltr" style="width: auto;">
      <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
          <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
            <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
              <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ConditionAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    obj = kwargs.get('instance')
    if obj:
        initial = [i for i in obj.registration.split(', ')]
        self.initial['registration'] = initial
```